# Making text change color in a function based on a result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, colors

i am trying to make the `marketStatus` function turn red when it returns `closed` and return green when it is returns `open`

here is the function

```
const marketStatus = () => {
    const date = getNewYorkTime();
    const day = date.getDay();
    const hour = date.getHours();
    const minutes = date.getMinutes();
    const seconds = date.getSeconds();
    const time = hour * 10000 + minutes * 100 + seconds;
    if (day === 0 || day === 6) {
      return "closed";
    } else if (time < 93000 || time > 160000) {
      return "closed";
    } else {
      return "open";
    }
  };
```

and here is where it is called in the code

```
<div className="username-container">
          <div className="username-badge">
            {" "}
            {greeting()} {Auth?.user?.username}, the NYSE is {marketStatus()}.{" "}
          </div>{" "}
        </div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hey LearningBeNice you can change the colour by passing conditionally like-

```
if (day === 0 || day === 6) {
return <p classname="text-color:red">closed</p>;
} else if (time < 93000 || time > 160000) {
return <p classname="text-color:red">closed</p>;
} else {
return <p classnmate="text-color:green">open</p>;
}
```

Please change this code with yours and check the result. If you still facing issue, lemme know, i will help you more.
Thanks